# Subtract the value of an IP Address from another

Tags: excel, ip, ip-address, subtraction

I have two cells in a sheet both containing an IP Address:

C2 = 192.168.0.1

C3 = 192.168.0.10

I want to subtract C2 from C3...giving me the result of 9.  The addresses will always have the same first three octets.  IN this example, 192.168.0 is constant in both cells.  It is only the last octet that will change.

Can this be done?  Everything I try, including Value and Value2 end in error.

So in say C4 my formula is

```
=C3-C2
or
=Value(c3)-Value(c2)
```

Gives errors.  I'm a total novice so be gentle.  Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do such arithmetic with IP addresses. How would you do 1.2.3.4 - 200.200.200.200? What would the difference even mean?

Comment: The values format to `Text`, so Excel is not interpreting them as numbers. So Excel will give an error when you're trying to subtract one string of text from another. In order to accomplish what you want, you have to assume that the first three value (192, 168, and 0) are indentical, Then you have to separate the last value from the string and subtract that.

Comment: Do you *only* want to subtract the last numbers?

Comment: What is the `use-case`. What are you going to do with the difference value? Do all devices have the `192.168.0` as common parts or are there different types as well. **Please update your question** for a better response

Comment: Actually, yes.  The last octet is the only issue.  The difference is always going to be one of several distinct numbers - 1,5, 13, 29, 61, 125 or 253.  Coming up with that number is key to auto filling a subnet mask field through the sheet.  I suppose I can create another field specifically for the last octet but it's not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to convert each IP address to a number, then subtract the numbers to get your difference. In several programming languages this function is called `inet_aton` (it stands for "internet array to number"). Googling "inet_aton excel" returns several links, [one of which](http://stuart.weenig.com/2011/05/excel-and-ip-addresses.html) gives a formula to do it:

`=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))*2^24+VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-FIND(".",A1)-1))*2^16+VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)+1)-FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-1))*2^8+VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)+1)))`

It's a mess, and I'm not going to verify it, but you should be able to use it to turn your IP addresses to numbers and subtract them.

The next page of that blog tells you how to add this formula as a custom Excel function, which you can then use.